# _vswprintf unresolved only for x64

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a right click context menu extension dll for Windows to support functionality in another program.

It's building fine targeting Win32, but when I try to build for x64, I get this

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vswprintf
```

I am not actually *calling* it anywhere in my code, so even if it is undefined, that shouldn't be a problem.  (I am including stdio.h, stdarg.h, and wchar.h though, so it *should* be defined.)

Comment: Are you using MSVC or MinGW compiler?

Comment: I'm using MSVC (VS 2008 specifically)